# Asset Catalog and RTL languages

Tags: ios, json, localization, assets

I am trying to make an `UIImage` (in an `UIImageView`) flip in an RTL language (in my case the phone's and app's language is arabic). I found an interesting opportunity when working with asset catalogs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH25-SW1

In **Table 16-1** there is the relevant key *language-direction* which seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However when I change the `Contents.json` accordingly the image does not get flipped.

This is how my modified `Contents.json` looks like:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "arrow-icon_512-512@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "language-direction" : "left-to-right"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "arrow-icon_512-512@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x",
      "language-direction" : "left-to-right"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Does anybody know what I am missing here? Or is this stuff not working at all? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like those asset localization features only work for Xcode >= 8. There you do not even have to edit the `Contents.json` file directly but can use options in the asset catalogue itself.

Comment: I got the newest XCode and still can't figure out how the add language dependent images / splash screens. Could you elaborate? Maybe with screen shots.?